# Subquery with multiple joins involved

Tags: sql

Still trying to get used to writing queries and I've ran into a problem.

```
Select count(region)
where (regionTable.A=1) in
(
select jxn.id, count(jxn.id) as counts, regionTable.A
from jxn inner join
               V on jxn.id = V.id inner join
               regionTable on v.regionID = regionTable.regionID
group by jxn.id, regionTable.A
)
```

The inner query gives an ID number in one column, the amount of times they appear in the table, and then a bit attribute if they are in region A.  The outer query works but the error I get is `incorrect syntax near the keyword IN`.  Of the inner query, I would like a number of how many of them are in region A

Comment: Can you describe what you want the query to return?

Comment: The inner query gives a list of several thousand IDs, the amount of times the ID is in the table, and whether or not they live in region A.  Some do, (1), some don't (0).  I want a subset of the query I just mentioned to return only the people who live in region A.  I believe that I have my queries backwards now.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify table name in query before where

```
  Select count(region)
    from table
    where (regionTable.A=1) in
```

And you must choose one of them.

```
where regionTable.A = 1
```

or

```
where regionTable.A in (..)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query has several syntax errors. Based on your comments, I think there is no need for a subquery and you want this:

```
select jxn.id, count(jxn.id) as counts, regionTable.A
from jxn inner join
               V on jxn.id = V.id inner join
               regionTable on v.regionID = regionTable.regionID
where regionTable.A = 1
group by jxn.id, regionTable.A
```

which can be further simplified to:

```
select jxn.id, count(jxn.id) as counts
     , 1 as A                             --- you can even omit this line
from jxn inner join
               V on jxn.id = V.id inner join
               regionTable on v.regionID = regionTable.regionID
where regionTable.A = 1
group by jxn.id
```

Comment: This is what I had prior to trying to do it with a sub query.  I'm trying to practice using sub queries :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of this line:

`where (regionTable.A=1)`

You cannot specify a condition in a `where in` clause, it should only be column name

Comment: when I that I get the error: multi-part identifier regionTable.A could not be bound.

Comment: Yeah you need to specify what you are selecting from in your first query.  Right now you are selecting from nothing.

Comment: Facepalm.  I'm doing this backwards I think.  What I want is a subset of the big select query (where regionA=1).  In that case what I have now as my outer query needs to be the inner, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
    (
        select jxn.id, count(jxn.id) as counts, regionTable.A 
        from 
            jxn inner join
            V on jxn.id = V.id inner join
            regionTable on v.regionID = regionTable.regionID 
        group by jxn.id, regionTable.A
    ) sq
WHERE sq.a = 1
```